# Why is an unused activity throwing an exception when uploaded to the Play Store?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app which I recently uploaded to the Play Store, with Crashlytics enabled. Within this app there is an activity called **StartQuizActivity**, which was created during development but is currently unused. The activity is still declared in the manifest, but there are no intents within the app which invoke it.

I received a crash report with the stack trace suggesting that a device had attempted to launch this activity, which resulted in an IllegalArgumentException, suggesting the required objects weren't passed with the intent:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.fractalwrench.acidtest/com.fractalwrench.acidtest.activities.StartQuizActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No extras supplied to
>   startQuizActivity!

**StartQuizActivity.java**

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        aminoAcid = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(AMINO_ACID);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (aminoAcid != null) {
             // do things
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No extras supplied to startQuizActivity!");
        }
```

Why would a device be able to launch this activity, given that there is no way to launch StartQuizActivity using the app's UI? I have noticed that the device was a rooted Nexus running API 21, and have seen similar crashes for other activities in the app. I have been unable to reproduce the crashes on any device, even after trying MonkeyRunner.

Is this some form of automated testing by Google or perhaps a user with a very specific device setup? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.StartQuizActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_title_prepare_for_quiz" />
```

Comment: I know with apps like Tasker you can directly start any Activity declared in any apps manifest. That is something that requires root.

Comment: Agreed, most likely, it's somebody messing with the app. Welcome to the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add an activity to your manifest with `android:exported="true"` (as is the default for activities), it becomes part of your public API that any app can call.

Understandably so, it is quite rare for other apps to explicitly start a random Activity from another app without reason, but apps such as [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) do allow end users to do exactly that.

You can either

1. Remove the activity from the manifest - this obviously removes any ability to start it at all
2. Add `android:exported="false"` - this ensures that other apps cannot start the Activity
3. Call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) if no extras were supplied, immediately stopping the activity.